# Nginx Rewrite Rule Similar to Apache's

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

In Apache you can use a RewriteRule to have address "/admin/categories/32/" pointing to "/admin/categories/".

Something like `RewriteRule ^/admin/categories/(.*)$ /admin/categories [L]`

How do I achieve the same with nginx? I was trying to get there with `rewrite regex dest last;` statement placed in `location / { ... }` block but to na avail.

I have a single page application sitting on /admin/categories/ and therefore I need the bit after /categories/ to be handled in the SPA and not considered by server a valid route.

Thanks

Comment: Is it because `location /` does not process this URI or because you get a rewrite loop? How is `/admin/categories` resolved by the server? Is it an index file? You may be able to use `try_files` instead of `rewrite`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your SPA is entirely JS, included in an HTML page at `<root>/admin/categories.html`:

```
root "/some/location";

location /admin/categories/ {
    try_files /admin/categories.html;
}
```

The parameter to the location block does a longest prefix match.